# What is the difference between these two different network security devices?

Tags: switch, router, network, firewall, networking

I have a choice between these two network security appliances, however the only difference I can see is the year and I don't know what that year means.

SONICWALL TZ300 WIRELESS-AC SECURE UPGRADE PLUS 3YR - 5 Port - 10/100/1000Base-T - Gigabit Ethernet - Wireless LAN IEEE 802.11ac - DES, 3DES, MD5, SHA-1, AES (128-bit), AES (192-bit), AES (256-bit) - 5 x RJ-45 - 3 Year

SONICWALL TZ300 WIRELESS-AC SECURE UPGRADE PLUS 2YR - 5 Port - 10/100/1000Base-T - Gigabit Ethernet - Wireless LAN IEEE 802.11ac - DES, 3DES, MD5, SHA-1, AES (128-bit), AES (192-bit), AES (256-bit) - 5 x RJ-45 - 2 Year

Comment: Are they priced the same?  My guess is one comes with 2 years of support and the other comes with 3 years.

Comment: (Paid) support is required for operating a security device like that - threats evolve constantly and their detection needs to be updated continuously in order to be effective.

Comment: Those are the same device but one of them is for 3 years and one of them is for 2 years. Have you considered asking?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In hardware descriptions such as the one you provided, a reference to "years" (YR) almost always refers to the duration of hardware and software support included with the purchase.

So one has two years of support included and the other has three.